# How to change column width in DataGridView which is filled by DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on a windows form application in C# , I have a data grid view which its DataSource is coming from a DataTable just like this

```
 DataTable table = projectsOperations.GetPaymentsByProjectId(this.ProjectID);

        dgvShowPaymentsOfProject.DataSource = table;
```

now i need to change the width of the column number 7 in the DataGridView i have tried this :

```
            dgvShowPaymentsOfProject.Columns[7].Width = 200;
```

but i gives me an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
can you guys please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Fun fact: column 7 would be `dgvShowPaymentsOfProject.Columns[6].Width = 200;` arrays and collections are zero based in c#.  Chapter 1 level stuff

Comment: thanks , but this does not answer my question , i am still getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dgvShowPaymentsOfProject.Columns[7];
column.Width = 200;
```

Or you can set auto size mode:

```
  dgvShowPaymentsOfProject.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 
        DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Or

```
dgvShowPaymentsOfProject.Columns[7].FillWeight = 200;
```

In addition, the number of indexes in `DataGridView` and also in `DataTable` starts from zero. If you have 7 fields and the field you want is the last field, i.e. the seventh field, you should introduce field number 6.
for example:

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dgvShowPaymentsOfProject.Columns[6];
column.Width = 200;
```

The above code is applied to the seventh field.
**And lastly, execute these codes after connecting the data source to the `DataGridView`. If you run before that, you will most likely get an error.**